# python3 socket recvfrom only receives data from netcat

Tags: python, sockets

I am attempting to create a simple python program for rtp sequence tracking but have run into an odd problem . I can see the rtp data on a tcpdump but when I run my script recvfrom just sits there , I confirmed the port is open with netstat , and if I send data using netcat the script does receive data .

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket, threading, time
import datetime, sys



def main():
    """
    MAIN
    """
    #udp = rxUdp()
    #udp.startUDPRx()

    udp_ip = '192.168.1.100'
    udp_port = 6022

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #IP/UDP
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    sock.bind(('', udp_port))
    #sock.bind(('eth1', 0))


    expected_rtp_seq = None
    print('Running')
    ts_file = open('test.ts', 'wb')
    #while True:
    for i in range (1, 1000):

        data = b''
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1500) #buffer size
        rtp_sequence_no = data[2:4]
        rtp_sequence_no = int.from_bytes(rtp_sequence_no, byteorder='big')

        rtp_len = data[19:20]

        mpegts_data = data[12:len(data)]
        print(rtp_sequence_no)
        print('.', end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        ts_file.write(mpegts_data)
        print(len(data))      
        if expected_rtp_seq == None:
            expected_rtp_seq = rtp_sequence_no
        if expected_rtp_seq != rtp_sequence_no:
            print('\n%s: Sequence Mismatch.  Expected %d, got %d' %
              (datetime.datetime.now(), expected_rtp_seq, rtp_sequence_no))
            expected_rtp_seq = rtp_sequence_no

        if expected_rtp_seq == 65535:
            expected_rtp_seq = 0
        else:
            expected_rtp_seq += 1


    ts_file.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I should mention this code does seem to work on windows 7 but not on ubuntu .

Here is the output of tcpdump for my rtp stream

> 10:26:57.486256 IP 209.87.232.169.57346 > 192.168.1.100.6022: UDP, length 1328
>       0x0000:  4500 054c 66e6 0000 3d11 95ad d157 e8a9  E..Lf...=....W..
>       0x0010:  c0a8 0164 e002 1786 0538 9797 8021 eddc  ...d.....8...!..
>       0x0020:  6512 e48b e7a0 747d 4700 6513            e.....t}G.e.

Here is the output of tcpdump from netcat

> 10:26:51.709234 IP 192.168.2.149.52305 > 192.168.2.241.6022: UDP, length 3
>       0x0000:  4500 001f 7d3c 4000 4011 36bb c0a8 0295  E...}<@.@.6.....
>       0x0010:  c0a8 02f1 cc51 1786 000b 22c0 6869 0a00  .....Q....".hi..
>       0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000            ............

Thanks for looking

Comment: Well, which IP is your program running on, `192.168.2.241` or `192.168.1.100`?

Comment: Your program works for me. Are you sure your ip address is correct, and that you are not trying to run in ubuntu with your windows computer ip address?  Try replacing ip address with 0.0.0.0 so that it listens to all interfaces.

Comment: If you look at my .bind you can see that I took out udp_ip so it would bind to all interfaces , my ubuntu machine has 192.168.1.100 eth1 and 192.168.2.241 eth2. It will accept messages from netcat on either interface it just doesn't seem to see the rtp data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys figured it out will leave my solution here if anyone else is banging their head against a wall.

So the issue was that 
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter, net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter, net.ipv4.conf.eth2.rp_filter
were all enabled found my answer here https://serverfault.com/a/216568.

Basically what these configs do is filter out any data that is not sourced from your local lan to prevent spoofing I set them all to 0 and the script fired up.

Thanks for the comments and taking the time to look .